# How to make a spiral array?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a spiral that looks like this:

```
21  22  23  24  25
20   7   8   9  10
19   6   1   2  11
18   5   4   3  12
17  16  15  14  13
```

But I can't start from the center.
What needs to be changed?
I don't know how to tune my loops.
The task was that I would start from the number that was given in the console and after that, in the form of a snail, the program produced this picture.
I have some ideas about middle int this array but it's not work.

Description: User input number 1, 2, 3.....
Program should output spiral array like this

I am try, but dont understand how to make it. My program print spiral array but not started in a middle array.

First i am find dimension array, after I find the numbers and put them in the array
but it doesn't work like that
My code:

```
int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int counter = 0;
// find size our matrix
for (int i = 1; i < m; i++)
{
    counter = i * i;

    if (counter >= m)
    {
        counter = i;
        break;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(counter);

int[,] arr2 = new int[counter, counter];

// add zero in array 
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++)
    {
        arr2[i, j] = 0;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine();

int count = 1;
int a = 0;
int midlle = counter - 2;

while (arr2[a, a] == 0)
{
    if (arr2[a, a] == 0)
    {
        
        for (int i = midlle; i <= midlle; i++)
        {
            for (int j = midlle; j < counter - midlle; j++)
            {
                arr2[i, j] = count;
                count++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1 + midlle; i < counter - midlle; i++)
        {
            for (int j = (counter - 1) - midlle; j == (counter - 1) - midlle; j++)
            {
                arr2[i, j] = count;
                count++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = (counter - 1) - midlle; i == (counter - 1) - midlle; i++)
        {
            for (int j = (counter - 2) - midlle; j >= 0 + midlle; j--)
            {
                arr2[i, j] = count;
                count++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = (counter - 2) - midlle; i > 0 + midlle; i--)
        {
            for (int j = 0 + midlle; j == 0 + midlle; j++)
            {
                arr2[i, j] = count;
                count++;
            }
        }
        a++;

    }
}


// add sticks and final result 
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < counter; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(arr2[i, j] + "|");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: *"I would start from the number that was given in the console"* <== In the example spiral shown (containing the numbers 1-25), what was the number given in the console?

Comment: *"But I can't start from the center."* <== Is this an externally imposed limitation?

Comment: I don't understand what the user input is for. Is it the starting value of the "snail"? Or is it somehow the starting *position*?

Comment: user input its max number in array

Answer (score 2):

I did not quite understand what you asked, but I will answer the question of "how to generate the spiral in the array".
Given n the size of one dimension of your array (that you call counter), we have 2 cases:

- first case n is odd : in this case the start of the spiral is at coordinates (floor(n/2),floor(n/2)).
- second case n is even : in this case we have 4 possible centers. If you want to start towards increasing X and increasing Y, the starting point should be at (n/2-1,n/2-1).

Then to generate the spiral, you need to consider the problem as a point that moves inside the array starting from the middle:

- first, the point moves 1 right and 1 bottom
- then, 2 left and 2 top
- then, 3 right and 3 bottom
- etc…

The question is then how many iterations of this motion should you do ? The answer is (n-1) iterations plus half an iteration to fill the rest of the array.

So the pseudo code to generate the spiral becomes :

```
int cx = (n-1)/2; //=floor(n/2) if n is odd and n/2-1 if n is even
int cy = (n-1)/2;

int cntr = 1;
arr[cx,cy] = cntr++;

int dir;

// n-1 iterations
for (int i=1; i<n; i++)
{
   dir = -1 + 2 * (i&1);

   for (int k=1; k<=i; k++)
   {
      cy += dir;
      arr[cx,cy] = cntr++;
   }
   for (int k=1; k<=i; k++)
   {
      cx += dir;
      arr[cx,cy] = cntr++;
   }
}

// the last half iteration to fill the last line
dir = -1 + 2 * (n&1);
for (int k=1; k<n; k++)
{
   cy += dir;
   arr[cx,cy] = cntr++;
}
```